# Generate HTML view template from JSON file

Tags: c#, html, jquery, json, angular

My task is to make application which will generate HTML view from JSON file.

I am attaching here JSON file and also HTML template.

Admin will edit OR make new JSON file and based on that HTML template should be generated.

I am free to open any framework, library etc..like Jquery, Razor, C# etc..

Here is example JSON file looks like..

**

```
"Screens": [
    {
        "Title": "Personal Information Form",
        "NavName": "Personal",
        "Sections":[
            {
                "layout": "full",
                "type": "HTML_P",
                "text": "Some quick information about yourself:"
            },
            {
                "layout": "two_columns",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "left_column": [
                            {
                                "type": "input",
                                "label": "First Name",
                                "required": true,
                                "placeholder": "Enter First Name",
                                "name": "fName",
                                "valid-feedback": "Valid.",
                                "invalid-feedback": "Please fill out this field."
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "date",
                                "label": "Birth Date:",
                                "required": true,
                                "placeholder": "Enter Birthdate",
                                "name": "dob",
                                "valid-feedback": "Valid.",
                                "invalid-feedback": "Please fill out this field."
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "checkbox",
                                "label": "Check All That Apply:",
                                "required": false,
                                "placeholder": null,
                                "name": null,
                                "valid-feedback": null,
                                "invalid-feedback": null,
                                "options": [
                                    {"label": "Option 1"},
                                    {"label": "Option 2"},
                                    {"label": "Option 3"}
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "right_column": [
                            {
                                "type": "input",
                                "label": "Last Name",
                                "required": true,
                                "placeholder": "Enter Last Name:",
                                "name": "lName",
                                "valid-feedback": "Valid.",
                                "invalid-feedback": "Please fill out this field."
                            },
```

**

Any reply will be very helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: you need to parse your JSON and set up the tags, read through the keys, and assign them to the HTML tags which you think suit the best as per the needs of the webpage you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an angular table would be useful to you.
Get the data from the JSON as needed and  generate the page according to the title and then the table with 2 columns can be generated.

Also you need to know how the json behaves in different scenarios. Based on the conditions you can create angular components based on it.

You need to show some work in order for us to help or guide you.